# Sum invloving Stiring number of the second kind and falling factorial

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, factorial, stirling-numbers

Is the value of the following summation can be expressed in a closed form?

$$
\Delta = \sum_{k=0}^{n} S(n,k) \; (C)_k \; m^k
$$

where $S(n,k)$ is [Stirling number of second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), $(C)_k$ is the falling factorial defined as $(C)_k:=C(C-1)\cdots (C-k+1)$ and $ 0< m <1$.

Comment: I just noticed that we can redefine the falling factorial as $(C)_k = {C \choose k} n!$ and arrive at $$
\Delta = \sum_{k=1}^n k!S(n, k){C \choose k} m^k.
$$ where it is  n-th moment of the binomial random variable posted at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1488422/a-sum-involving-stirling-numbers-of-the-second-kind?rq=1. Is this possible to get a close expression for it?

Comment: A generalization of this sum is posted at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1486986/a-combinatorial-sum-and-identity-involving-stirling-numbers-of-the-second-kind

Comment: This question is duplicate of  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1735707/is-there-a-closed-form-expression-for-this-sum-involving-stirling-number-of-seco